# FlashDevelop embedding swf "Definition for symbol not found"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop, embedding

I am trying to embed a symbol from a swf and getting the following error: Definition for symbol 'ball' not found.
This is the code

```
package
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    [Embed(source="lib/Assets/Assets.swf", symbol="ball")]
    public var ballCls:Class;
    public var ball:MovieClip = new ballCls;
    public function Main()
    {

    }
}
```

I keep getting this

Error:definition for symbol 'ball' not found.

Error:unable to transcode /lib/Assets/Assets.swf.

I am using Flashdevelop and the symbol was made with VectorianGiotto and has a simple tween animation.

If i remove the tween and export it then it works. Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:
Assets.swf

SWF version: 8

AVM: 1

Comment: Maybe export as SWC instead? Also check if FlashDevelop GUI is able to enumerate the SWF. Also check for the SWF version, perhaps it's bigger than your FD supports - update FD, if so.

Comment: I am a new at all this only started learning as3 recently, so how do i check if Flashdevelop is enumerating the SWF? Also the SWF version of Assets.swf is 8. Lastly how can i switch to a SWC format?

Comment: If you are able to expand the SWF if selected in the tree view of FlashDevelop, then FD can enumerate the SWF. In order to switch to SWC format, you have to open that SWF in Adobe Flash and there is an "Export to SWC" command available. But SWF version = 8 means the SWF is pretty old, perhaps you really need to convert it to SWC to first make it newer, and second, its code is probably in AS1 or AS2, which causes the error.

Comment: Well actually i am using vectorian giotto because i don't have adobe flash and that's how it exports it. So how can i change the code to as3? I mean is that possible at all using the same software or do i need to find something else?

Comment: If so, try searching for settings in what ActionScript level to export the SWF from Vectorian Giotto. Maybe there is a setting to export as AS3, then set that and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't have such an option and from the searching i did it uses as2. Anyway thanks for the replies and help, i guess i'll try to find some other freeware or just buy Adobe's Flash.